# FXG Editor for Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, fxg

The only FXG editor I've seen for Flex is [by 7jigen, works online or 
as a Flex app](http://labs.7jigen.net/2010/05/15/fxg-editor-air-app/).

Does anyone know of a different one? It can be done in Illustrator I think, but that doesn't really offer a simple export to Flex type option, just gives coordinates.

[image]

Comment: I removed the new tag request, as someone has added [fxg] to the question, and fixed some minor stuff ("doesnt" > "doesn't").

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know your best bet (if you don't want to use Illustrator) is to grab [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) and install the "save as FXG" plug-in. Hats off to [JazzyNico](https://twitter.com/jazzynico) for writing what is basically a **monster** SVG to FXG "XSL Transform" (i.e. XSLT).

How to install:

1. Install [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).
2. Grab the plug-in files [svg2fxg.inx](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/trunk/download/nicoduf@yahoo.fr-20101221203555-f6dxgat5u7f19szg/svg2fxg.inx-20101221203409-pt9ao3mfg54jc8g3-1/svg2fxg.inx) and [svg2fxg.xsl](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/trunk/download/nicoduf@yahoo.fr-20110114110437-k84q1kubm2ojkh1x/svg2fxg.xsl-20101221203409-pt9ao3mfg54jc8g3-2/svg2fxg.xsl).
3. Drop both files in your Inkscape "extensions" folder.

   - In GNU/Linux: `$HOME/.config/inkscape/extensions`
   - In Windows: `C:\Documents and Settings\User\Application Data\Inkscape\extensions`
   - In OSX: `/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/extensions`
4. Restart Inkscape and you'll find a new FXG entry in the "File > Save As" dialog.

This plugin has been a boon for me and my work, since I've become quite comfortable with Inkscape over the years.

*Unfortunately* (and this may just be my setup), I've found that whenever I save as FXG, a few minutes later Inkscape crashes out (I really should post a bug report). Just in case you have the same problem, make sure you go to the "Save" preferences and turn on auto-backup. Also, keep in mind that certain constructs in SVG have no equivalent in FXG. Don't ask me what they are, I honestly can't remember.

Comment: Flash CS 5.5 crashes when trying to import Inkscape generated FXG

Answer (score 3):

I have used this process to generate a ton of FXG assets that I have imported into my Flex projects.

1. Draw the shape in Flash CS5
2. Break the shape apart (Ctrl+B)
3. Select the shape
4. File -> Export -> Export Selection
5. Save as FXG

You can then import them directly into Flex and voila! Good to go!

Answer (score 3):

Use Inkscape SVG editor: it will allows you to convert svg to fxg starting [version 0.49](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.49#Import.2FExport) thanks to the svg2fxg plug-in.

In the mean time (version 0.48) you can install the svg2fxg plug-in manually as explained by **RIAGrande**:

1. Install Inkscape http://inkscape.org/download/
2. Get the 2 svg2fxg plug-in files from here (from **head** repository):

   > http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/trunk/view/head:/share/extensions/svg2fxg.inx
   >
   > http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/trunk/view/head:/share/extensions/svg2fxg.xsl
3. and copy them in Inkscape extension folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\share\extensions on Windows 7)

You can now start Inkscape and will get a new "File -> Save As -> Flash XML graphics (*.svg)" entry.

I successfully tested it and used the fxg generated assets in on IPhone: it works fine :-)

Comment: Is this the same as the answer by myself? Or has the updates by inkscape made it easier

Comment: The point in my answer is that the svg extensions should be get from head repository, and not using RIAGrande's links. Head versions seems more stables (no crashes for me). For the rest, the answer is basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly, RIAGrande's answer is correct. I followed his steps and they worked. Here is a little more information for future reference:**

The Inkscape bug report for FXG with downloads available under Patches can be found at
https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/625140. These files (when uncompressed) should be copied to the location mentioned by RIAGrande

I made my little icon, but he exported FXG file was not indented, so used http://xmlindent.com/ to fomat the file, Downloaded, copied to my project in Flash Builder and renamed as **.fxg** file.

To use the FXG file, did the following:

```
<s:Group>
    <local:fxgInkscapeIcon height="100" width="100" x="50" y="50"/> 
</s:Group>
```

For posterity, here is the icon and resulting Inkscape FXG code:

[image: Image created in Inkscape]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Graphic xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008" xmlns:fxg="http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008" xmlns:d="http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008/dt" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-tiny.dtd" version="2.0" viewWidth="16" viewHeight="16">
    <mask>
        <Group>
            <Rect width="16" height="16">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#ffffff" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Rect>
        </Group>
    </mask>
    <!--Unknown tag: defs-->
    <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
    <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
    <Group id="layer1">
        <Group id="g3219">
            <Path data="m 3.4494939 4.7212002 2.7832822 -2.6455548 0 3.6343941 -2.7832822 1.0225951 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3231">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#E9E9FF" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="m 2.4777228 4.4673265 0 2.1671775 0.9717711 0.098131 0 -2.0114344 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3221">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#353564" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="M 2.4777228 4.4673265 4.7752476 1.1915748 6.2327761 2.0756454 3.4494939 4.7212002 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3223">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#4D4D9F" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="M 2.4777228 6.634504 4.7752476 5.3683167 6.2327761 5.7100395 3.4494939 6.7326346 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3229">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#AFAFDE" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="m 4.7752476 1.1915748 0 4.1767419 1.4575285 0.3417228 0 -3.6343941 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3227">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#D7D7FF" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="m 2.4777228 4.4673265 2.2975248 -3.2757517 0 4.1767419 -2.2975248 1.2661873 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3225">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#8686BF" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
        </Group>
        <Group id="g3233">
            <Path data="M 2.7930693 12.065864 4.7752475 14.951316 6.232776 14.048691 3.8532769 11.73947 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3243">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#AFAFDE" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="m 2.7930693 9.5192088 0 2.5466552 1.0602076 -0.326394 0 -2.3422182 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3235">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#353564" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="m 3.8532769 9.3972518 2.3794991 0.8628392 0 3.7886 -2.3794991 -2.309221 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3245">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#E9E9FF" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="M 2.7930693 9.5192088 4.7752475 10.597357 6.232776 10.260091 3.8532769 9.3972518 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3237">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#4D4D9F" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="m 4.7752475 10.597357 0 4.353959 1.4575285 -0.902625 0 -3.7886 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3241">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#D7D7FF" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="m 2.7930693 9.5192088 1.9821782 1.0781482 0 4.353959 -1.9821782 -2.885452 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3239">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#8686BF" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
        </Group>
        <Group id="g3247">
            <Path data="M 4.7301981 10.623124 8.739604 12.846535 10.29713 11.806839 6.1815487 10.285313 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3257">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#800080" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="m 4.7301981 5.3683167 0 5.2548073 1.4513506 -0.337811 0 -4.5780822 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3249">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#800080" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="M 6.1815487 5.7072308 10.29713 4.18074 l 0 7.626099 -4.1155813 -1.521526 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3259">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#800080" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="M 4.7301981 5.3683167 8.739604 3.1376518 10.29713 4.18074 6.1815487 5.7072308 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3251">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#800080" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="m 8.739604 3.1376518 0 9.7088832 1.557526 -1.039696 0 -7.626099 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3255">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#800080" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
            <Path data="m 4.7301981 5.3683167 4.0094059 -2.2306649 0 9.7088832 -4.0094059 -2.223411 z" winding="evenOdd" id="path3253">
                <fill>
                    <SolidColor color="#800080" alpha="1"/>
                </fill>
            </Path>
        </Group>
        <Path data="M 6.7296153 11.713583 4.7609632 10.626386 4.7586994 8.0107245 4.7564356 5.3950627 4.88976 5.2964917 c 0.073328 -0.054214 0.1452487 -0.098571 0.1598229 -0.098571 0.021999 0 0.9221556 -0.4946803 1.1484369 -0.6311227 C 6.2351856 4.544388 6.5155757 4.3883429 6.8211089 4.2200312 7.1266421 4.0517194 7.4712708 3.8603428 7.5869505 3.7947497 7.8155129 3.6651495 8.0560806 3.5353764 8.3378713 3.3896691 8.4369802 3.3384223 8.5536701 3.2649336 8.5971821 3.226361 c 0.043512 -0.038573 0.089217 -0.060028 0.1015661 -0.047679 0.012349 0.012349 0.017293 2.1823735 0.010986 4.822276 l -0.011467 4.7998228 -1.968652 -1.087198 z" winding="nonZero" id="path3261">
            <fill>
                <SolidColor color="#FF00FF" alpha="1"/>
            </fill>
        </Path>
        <Path data="m 2.5039603 5.4963957 c 0 -0.6060218 0.015204 -1.1086152 0.033787 -1.1168743 0.052529 -0.023346 0.2815594 -0.3415436 0.2815594 -0.3911774 0 -0.024366 0.015204 -0.051058 0.033787 -0.059318 0.052529 -0.023346 0.2815594 -0.3415436 0.2815594 -0.3911774 0 -0.024366 0.015204 -0.051059 0.033787 -0.059318 C 3.2209698 3.455185 3.45 3.1369877 3.45 3.0873539 c 0 -0.024366 0.015204 -0.051058 0.033787 -0.059318 0.052529 -0.023346 0.2815594 -0.3415435 0.2815594 -0.3911773 0 -0.024366 0.01689 -0.051059 0.037534 -0.059318 0.020644 -0.00826 0.2131642 -0.26842 0.4278232 -0.5781353 0.214659 -0.3097154 0.4207638 -0.6027185 0.4580106 -0.6511181 0.060562 -0.078696 0.067721 0.1266999 0.067721 1.942875 0 1.5702733 -0.012771 2.0412475 -0.056312 2.0766116 C 4.6691522 5.3929299 4.2485024 5.6303359 3.7653465 5.8953434 3.2821906 6.1603507 2.800724 6.4269177 2.6954207 6.4877142 l -0.1914604 0.1105394 0 -1.1018579 z" winding="nonZero" id="path3263">
            <fill>
                <SolidColor color="#00FF00" alpha="1"/>
            </fill>
        </Path>
        <Path data="M 3.7705821 13.453243 2.8195554 12.06797 2.8194311 10.814691 2.8193069 9.5614117 3.1684406 9.7516131 c 0.1920235 0.1046107 0.5473426 0.2988019 0.789598 0.4315359 0.2422554 0.132735 0.4644582 0.246219 0.493784 0.252187 0.055299 0.01126 0.1254459 0.05844 0.2386022 0.160481 0.056179 0.05066 0.066011 0.371061 0.066011 2.151114 0 1.150371 -0.00784 2.091584 -0.017413 2.091584 -0.00958 0 -0.4453754 -0.623373 -0.9684401 -1.385272 z" winding="nonZero" id="path3265">
            <fill>
                <SolidColor color="#FF0000" alpha="1"/>
            </fill>
        </Path>
        <Path data="m 2.5251337 5.4884758 0.033034 -1.06093 0.1780729 -0.256768 C 2.8341803 4.0295554 2.9845892 3.8126485 3.0704822 3.6887623 3.1563752 3.5648762 3.2921089 3.3701098 3.3721127 3.2559482 3.4521166 3.1417866 3.6000512 2.9289277 3.7008563 2.7829284 3.8016614 2.6369291 4.0652011 2.2657195 4.2864999 1.958018 l 0.4023615 -0.5594572 0.022525 0.942378 c 0.012389 0.5183079 0.012389 1.4067712 0 1.9743628 L 4.6888614 5.3472865 3.6144 5.9483464 C 3.0234462 6.2789291 2.5291749 6.5494059 2.5160193 6.5494059 c -0.013156 0 -0.00905 -0.4774184 0.00911 -1.0609301 z" winding="nonZero" id="path3267">
            <fill>
                <SolidColor color="#FF0000" alpha="1"/>
            </fill>
        </Path>
    </Group>
</Graphic>
```