# Using FXG in the real world

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, fxg

Has anybody found examples of using FXG files in real world applications?

Comment: This is not really a technical question related to programming, so I voted to close.  Why do you need to know this?  A better question is if FXG will work for your specific use case; but even that would be off-topic.  My game ( https://market.android.com/details?id=air.com.igorKnots.magondaMaze&hl=en ) uses FXG elements for the primary game board, and most of the backgrounds.

Comment: Yes this is a good example of using the FXG, in this case to describe background pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, [Adobe Illustrator](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator.html) saves in FXG format.

Other Adobe applications supporting FXG include Fireworks, Flash, Illustrator, Photoshop and Flash Catalyst.

Microsoft Expression Blend [allows importing FXG 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ff979328%28v=expression.40%29.aspx).

On the open-source side, [SpecFXGExport](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/SpecFXGExport) enhances [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) to export FXG files.

Additionally, this might be of interest: [FXG Editor for Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554455/fxg-editor-for-flex).