# How would one use vector graphics from inkscape in flash develop?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flashdevelop, inkscape

when I create vector images in InkScape or any similar program. How would I embed them or otherwise load them in flashdevelop? I've been googling for a while but I am stuck now. I tried the following:

- .svg with regular embed code -> works, but with no gradients. Also colors seems to be strange.
- .emf with regular embed code -> doesn't work I get an error
- .wmf with regular embed code -> doesn't work, I get the same error
- Using the class load method -> doesn't recognise any of the files as importable

The error:

- Error: '../../lib/art/GreenTank.emf' does not have a recognized extension, and a mimeType was not provided
- Error: Unable to transcode ../../lib/art/GreenTank.emf.

I was wondering if there was another way of accomplishing this. Or if I did anything wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put up an question similar to this before, and detailed how to use the Inkskape fxgs in flex, maybe that will help:

[FXG Editor for Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554455/fxg-editor-for-flex/5562924#5562924)

Comment: That is indeed the plugin I was refering too. Thank you for your post.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Found it.

FGX is the format to go. It supports most of the inkscape features and inkscape can save to this format with an extension(svg2fxg).